# Get list of string from list of Json object

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I am trying to extract list of string from following Json

```
"example":{[
{"@name":"name1"},
{"@name":"name2"},
{"@name":"name3"},
{"@name":"name4"}
]}
```

I want to get the list of @name values. I am using jayway jsonpath to do this.

I tried the following code,

```
List<String> response = null;
    try{
      ReadContext ctx = JsonPath.parse(data);
      response = ctx.read(xPath);
    }catch(Exception e){
      AppLogger.EventLogger.error(e.getMessage());
      response = null;
    }
    return response;
```

but got an exception saying could not find the specified path. I have used the following jsonPath `example.@name`

Can someone tell me What went wrong in my code? how to extract list @name values.

Expected output :

```
[name1,name2,name3,name4]
```

Comment: First of all it doesn't look like valid json...

Comment: @SouravGanguly, Thanks. but consider  it is valid Json :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made small changes to your json in order to make it valid.

```
{"example":[
{"@name":"name1"},
{"@name":"name2"},
{"@name":"name3"},
{"@name":"name4"}
]}
```

and the code which specified works perfectly fine with the following expression:
    **$.example[*].@name**

There are a lot of online services which can help validate your json. 
One of them is [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

I would also recommend to look at [json.org](http://www.json.org/).